# Strict ceiling and floor notation

Tags: notation

The normal ceiling and floor functions, denoted $\lceil x \rceil$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ respectively, refer to the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$, and similar for the floor function.

I have a need for some notation to represent the smallest integer strictly greater than $x$, or similar for 'strict floor'.

I've had a google and nothing came up, and I'd prefer not to make up notation if some already exists. Has anyone come across notation for this before?

Comment: Why not use $\lceil \overline x\rceil$ and $\lfloor \underline x\rfloor$, or something to that effect.

Comment: @JordanGlen That notation works great, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, Cameron!

Comment: @Vikram That doesn't work. Consider $x = 0.95$ in $\lceil x + 0.1 \rceil$.

Comment: @Vikram I want the *smallest* integer strictly greater than $x$.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that *strict ceil* is equal to $ 1 -  \lceil - x \rceil $, and  *srtict floor* is $ - 1 - \lfloor - x \rfloor $.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given, I would like to add:

*If you cannot easily find the notation for what you are doing, it is definitely not standardized (the Schur/Hadamard product comes to mind). You can also expect the reader not to be familiar with any notation, and thus choose what's most convenient.*

Just be sure to define the notation clearly in whatever report/thesis/assignemnt you are writing.

Comment: @JordanGlen Oops, I meant it to be cursive. That looks better.

Comment: I'd definitely define it for the reader regardless of which notation I used, I was more looking for examples that other people had come up with, so I can pick one that I like. From the answers I'm getting, maybe I didn't make that clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about use $\lceil x+\rceil$ for the strict ceiling, and $\lfloor x-\rfloor$ for strict floor? (Sometimes we write $f(x+):= \lim_{u\downarrow x} f(u)$ and $f(x-):= \lim_{u\uparrow x}f(u)$.)